# What is our stance on questions specific to unsupported browsers?

Tags: discussion, scope, browsers

What is our stance on questions specific to browsers that Stack Exchange doesn't support? Should we still keep them to help people who use these browsers, or close/downvote them?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you mean questions like bugs happening while using a browser that turns out to be not supported according to [the official FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need?), I usually won't downvote or close as off topic as it still about Stack Exchange.

First of all, I'll post a comment saying the browser is not supported, linking to the FAQ. If there's value to others, I might close as duplicate to give a better indication.

Some edge cases can be, for example, someone using an **obviously unsupported** browser like [Internet Explorer 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6), or someone who insists that Stack Exchange should still fix the bug or support a browser they're using - in such cases I might cast a downvote and back away.

Comment: Thanks! "I might close as duplicate to give a better indication" -> close a dupe of the official faq?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt yes, of the faq.

Comment: This answer assumes that IE6 was actually a *browser*, as opposed to, say, garbageware masquerading as a low-quality browser.

Comment: @Robert sadly enough, IE6 **is still in use by thousands** (most likely all of them are places like banks who refuse to spend money on upgrading their system) so yeah, while garbage it's still a thing. :/